# Notifying a user when a file appears in a folder

Tags: windows-7, task-scheduler

We currently have Google Drive running on our server to transfer files back and forth with another location. We've gotten pretty big files sometimes, and it's tedious having to keep checking to see if the upload and download are both finished.

So my thought was that surely I could set up the Task Scheduler to do this (I'm on Windows 7). I'd want it to run when a log shows that a file was created inside a certain folder that should be watched. However I don't know where I'd find that in the logs, and I'm unsure whether the log would be different or perhaps even non existent since it would be the server machine that actually receives the file.

Can anyone help figure out how to approach this?

Comment: Personal option: Pretty sure Google Drive don't have this function built-in with, and it even don't have a function to force syncing now, recommend you to move to Dropbox for less headache. Technical speaking: You may create a batch script (most simple) or VB script to compare folder/files change in every N second, if there is changes, pop up a window/play some sound or whatever you like.

Comment: @Bilo Unfortunately switching isn't an option for us, we have to stick with Drive. The batch script feels like a messy approach but I that doesn't mean there's an actual reason it's a bad idea.